# Third central moment Bernoulli variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm looking for a proof of the third central moment of a Bernoulli variable $X$ with probability $p$. I know it must be $p(1-p)(1-2p)$, but I'm looking for a way to show this. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: welcome the MSE.As this is your first question I want to tell you your responsibility do not end with asking the question.You should show some effort from your own so that another person do not repeat your attempt and if you find something useful content regarding your question then mention anytime.Good luck

Answer (score 3):

This is just an application of the definition of the third central moment. What's the mean of a Bernoulli variable? Subtract that from the two possible values, take the third powers, multiply by the probabilities, add, factor out $p(1-p)$, and you're done.